# How to send ack to netcat and then keep the connection alive?

Tags: python, bash, shell, telnet, netcat

I try make connection using natcat on my server. but server need ack in every 180 to make connection alive.
i try to make connection using following command.

```
cat sample.xml | nc -q -1 192.168.1.1 4747>value.xml
```

sample.xml file contain ack which I need to send every 180sec to make connection alive.
without ack connection close after 180 sec.

i want a connection which linstion continuously and send sample.xml file every 180 sec. if i try (-q -1) to make connection alive. client close the connection after 180 sec. if ack not send. so how i send ack on every 180th sec to listien continouesly without and distrubance

Comment: Sorry, it's really unclear what/how you're trying to accomplish something here. Do you need `while sleep 180 ; do cat sample.xml ..... ; done` ? Please don't reply in comments, but update your question with your best attempt to solve your problem, Is the attempt "to make connection alive (every 180secs)" happening independently of another main process that is also connected? Again, update your Q please. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter i want a connection which linstion continuously and send sample.xml file every 180 sec. if i try (-q -1) to make connection alive. client close the connection after 180 sec. if ack not send.